# How to select certain digits from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex expression: `(GTO|YHG)|(\d{2,4})` using this sample string:

Feature/GTO-1466 Errors Collection responses should be empty not 404

Feature/YHG-91 Sprint 4 Epic

It will match the following:

```
GTO1466

YHG91

404
```

The output that I need is:

```
GTO1466

YHG91
```

Essentially I want to get rid off the `404`

I tried several variations from the above expression, mainly trying to exclude a digit from the end of a line, but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: change the regex to `(GTO|YHG)\d{2,4}`

Comment: I just tried in regex101.com but It doesn't seem to match anything?

Comment: oh didn't see the dash so `(GTO|YHG)\-\d{2,4}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the OR and Use the first and second Capturing Groups for

```
(GTO|YHG)-(\d{2,4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/wxfJZ8/2

Comment: Removing the OR doesn't seem to work as it doesn't match anything

Comment: You can use the hyphen, if you are sure there is a hyphen for every entry. Check the link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Answer (score 1):

```
(GTO|YHG).(\d{2,4})
```

This one works according to: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Is this possible to without using grouped matches? so what I mean is without using the () I did try GTO|YHG.\d{2,4} but it excludes 1466 https://regex101.com/r/wxfJZ8/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Negative Lookahead, ?!, with your number, 404. Just add (?!404) with in one parenthesis your /d.

source: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookahead

Comment: Is this possible to do without grouping the matches? e.g without using () For example, GTO|YHG|\d{2,4}|\d?!404 doesn't exclude the 404